# Add newline after every period in the document

Tags: line-breaking, programming

Is there a way to make every period (dot) act like \newline command ?

The only way I can think of now is to write shell-script to do it for me.

Comment: Try adding ``{\catcode`\.=\active\gdef.{\newline}}\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`\.=\active}`` to you preamble.  Expect major breakage.

Comment: What about decimal numbers such as 3.14 and 2.71?

Comment: @HenriMenke I know some people that use this as a writing guideline (see for example http://algorithmicallyrandom.blogspot.com/2014/03/one-sentence-per-line.html). Finding out if a period is an end-of-line or just part of an abbreviation or number is hard however, as Mico commented. If you use Emacs then you may be able to repurpose a plugin like https://github.com/jeeger/twauctex to automatically insert a `\newline` command in the LaTeX source code.

Comment: @Marijn The blog you linked refers to a newline after every sentence in the input source file, not in the resulting output.

Comment: @HenriMenke not really, the blog also talks about e-mails (which is the use case I am familiar with), so it is not only intended to help the author while writing but also to make it easier to understand for the reader that receives the 'end product' (an e-mail or compiled tex document). However, it may very well be that writing considerations are the primary reason for this practise, and that the fact that the reader sees it too, in an email for example, is a (maybe unfortunate) side effect.

Comment: Why not simply in the source find/replace the period `.` by `\newline`?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I can imagine you wanting it in your source code to help you read it but I can imagine having it in the typeset result will not help but rather confuse the reader.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will assume that you wish to insert `\newline` not only after `.` ("period", "full stop") characters but also after question marks and exclamation marks -- but not within decimal numbers such as `3.14159` or strings such as `tex.stackexchange.com`. Put differently, `\newline` should get inserted only if `.?!` is followed by whitespace or occurs at the very end of an input line. If you wish to override this setting, say, to keep `C. Ph. E. Bach` on one line, you'll have to input the name either as `C.\ Ph.\ E.\ Bach` or (if you wish to *prevent* line breaks) as `C.~Ph.~E.~Bach`.

If my working assumption is correct, and if you're free to use LuaLaTeX, the following solution may be of interest to you. Note that I make no claims as to robustness. In fact, the solution is likely not robust at all.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
function dot2newline ( s )
   s = s:gsub ( "([%.%?!])%s+" , "%1\\newline " ) 
   s = s:gsub ( "([%.%?!])$"   , "%1\\newline " )
   return s
end
\end{luacode}
\AtBeginDocument{\directlua{ luatexbase.add_to_callback (
   "process_input_buffer" , dot2newline , "dot2newline" )}}
 
\begin{document}
\setlength\parindent{0pt} % just for this example

Hello. Hello? Hello! $0.0<1.0$.  3.14159. \texttt{tex.stackexchange.com}. 
... ...
Hi!
Where?
C.\ Ph.\ E.\ Bach
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Textual replacements in the input file, as shown in Mico's answer, should work fine for this use-case but require LuaTeX.  You can also achieve something similar with just TeX macros, however, this will blow up if a macro relies on the fact that punctuation has category code 12 (like TikZ).

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\protected\def\mynewline#1{%
    \def\@@mynewline{\@mynewline{#1}}%
    \futurelet\next\@@mynewline
}
\def\@mynewline#1{%
    \char`#1
    \TextOrMath{%
        \ifx\next\@sptoken
            \expandafter\newline
        \fi
    }{}%
}

\makeatother

{\catcode`\.=\active\gdef.{\mynewline{.}}
 \catcode`\?=\active\gdef?{\mynewline{?}}
 \catcode`\!=\active\gdef!{\mynewline{!}}}
\AtBeginDocument{
    \catcode`\.=\active
    \catcode`\?=\active
    \catcode`\!=\active
}

\begin{document}
\setlength\parindent{0pt} % just for this example

Hello. Hello? Hello! $0.0<1.0$.  3.14159. \texttt{tex.stackexchange.com}. 
... ...
Hi!
Where?
C.\ Ph.\ E.\ Bach
\end{document}
```